Задача на перевод символов в Rot13
Решаю задание на Codewars, где самому нужно сделать функцию, которая реализует шифр Rot13.
Его идея в следующем:

ROT13 — это простой шифр замены букв, который заменяет букву буквой, находящейся через 13 букв после неё в алфавите. Если в строку включены цифры или специальные символы, их следует вернуть в исходном виде. Смещать следует только буквы латинского/английского алфавита.

Мой код работает более чем с половиной значений, но я не понимаю, почему в некоторых моментах моя функция и перевод с помощью codecs.encode() дают разные результаты.
Например, для 'test' выдаёт 'grfg' везде. А вот со строкой 'aA bB zZ 1234 *!?%' уже возникают различия:

моя функция: mM nN mM 1234 *!?%
встроенная: nN oO mM 1234 *!?%

Сам код:
alphabet = {1:'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'c', 5: 'd', 6: 'e', 7: 'f', 8: 'g', 9: 'h', 10: 'i', 11: 'j', 12: 'k', 13: 'l', 14: 'm',15: 'n', 16: 'o', 17: 'p', 18: 'q', 19: 'r', 20: 's', 21: 't', 22: 'u', 23: 'v', 24: 'w', 25: 'x', 26: 'y', 27: 'z'}

def rot13(message):
    mass = []
    for n in message:
        if n.isalpha():
            for k, v in alphabet.items():
                if n.lower() == alphabet[k]:
                    if n.islower():
                        if k + 13 <= 27:
                            mass.append(alphabet[k + 13])
                            break
                        else:
                            mass.append(alphabet[k - 13])
                            break
                    else:
                        if k + 13 <= 27:
                            mass.append(alphabet[k + 13].upper())
                            break
                        else:
                            mass.append(alphabet[k - 13].upper())
                            break
        else:
            mass.append(n)
    return ''.join(mass)

print(rot13('aA bB zZ 1234 *!?%'))


Вам не помешало бы параллельно ещё на каком-нибудь сайте вроде Бесплатный курс Python (питон), самостоятельное обучение программированию с нуля заниматься

@rotabor и зачем? Ошибка-то в чем тут?

Вас не смущает, что в латинском алфавите 26, а не 27 символов?

Вы бы смогли alphabet как-то путно сгенерировать - не было бы этой ошибки.

@MBo, точно... не заметил совсем - спасибо большое!!!

3: 'c', 4: 'c' - ну сразу же в глаза бросается )   И да, как минимум можно было через enumerate не нумеровать вручную, но уже ещё лучше способы написали.

Ошибка в инициализации алфавита
alphabet = {1:'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e', 6: 'f', 7: 'g', 8: 'h', 9: 'i', 10: 'j', 11: 'k', 12: 'l', 13: 'm',14: 'n', 15: 'o', 16: 'p', 17: 'q', 18: 'r', 19: 's', 20: 't', 21: 'u', 22: 'v', 23: 'w', 24: 'x', 25: 'y', 26: 'z'}


Не надо так. Алфавит можно сгенерировать без ручной нумерации символов.

[chr(i) for i in range(65, 91)]

def rot13(text, rot=13):
    new_text = ''
    for s in text: # Перебираем все символы
        num = ord(s) # Порядковый номер символа
        if ord('A') <= num <= ord('Z'); # Заглавные буквы A-Z
            new = (num - ord('A') + rot) % 26 + ord('A')
        elif ord('a') <= num <= ord('z'): # Строчные буквы a-z
            new = (num - ord('a') + rot) % 26 + ord('a')
        else: # Другие символы
            new = num
        new_text += chr(new)
    return new_text

text = 'Hello, world!'
new_text = rot13(text)


"Магические константы" - это плохо. Лучше было написать через тот же ord('A') и т.п.

Вот, другое дело. Мне кажется, так гораздо понятнее, что тут за магия происходит в вычислениях. )  Осталось ещё для константы 26 хорошее имя придумать, но тут не настаиваю уже )  Я бы вообще ротацию символа в отдельный метод зарефакторил %)

Сама задача решается в одну строку. Все остальные строки - подготовка данных:
import string

src_lc = string.ascii_lowercase
src_uc = string.ascii_uppercase

dst_lc = src_lc[13:] + src_lc[:13]
dst_uc = src_uc[13:] + src_uc[:13]

src = src_lc + src_uc
dst = dst_lc + dst_uc

table = str.maketrans(src, dst)

print(input().translate(table))


Да, данные - это всегда главное.
